# A problem related to mean value theorem and taylor's formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I guess I need to use Taylor's formula and the mean value theorem. I have no idea except for them. 
Note: honestly, this is not homework. I am studying by myself.

Suppose that $f\colon\mathbf{R}^2\to\mathbf{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^p$ on $B_r(x_0,y_0)$ for some $r>0$. Prove that, given $(x,y)\in B_r(x_0,y_0)$, there is a point $(c,d)$ on the line segment between $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$ such that
$$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(x-x_0)^j(y-y_0)^{k-j}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x^k\partial y^{k-j}}(x_0,y_0)\right)\\
+\frac{1}{p!}\sum_{j=0}^p\binom{p}{j}(x-x_0)^j(y-y_0)^{p-j}\frac{\partial^p f}{\partial x^k\partial y^{p-j}}(c,d)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive it from the analogous single-variable version by defining $\mathbf{v}(t) = (x_0, y_0) + t(x-x_0, y-y_0)$, and looking at the function $\phi(t)=f(\mathbf{v}(t))$. We do a Taylor expansion for $\phi$ centered at $t=0$, approximating at the point $t=1$.

For instance, if we want to take $p=2$, the single-variable Taylor theorem tells us that $\phi(1) = \phi(0) + \phi'(0)\cdot1 + \phi''(t^*)\cdot1$ for $t^*\in (0,1)$. By the chain rule, $$\phi'(0)=f_1(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_2(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0), \text{ and}$$  $$\phi''(t^*)=\left\langle H_f(t^*)\left(\begin{matrix}x-x_0 \\ y - y_0\end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix}x-x_0 \\ y - y_0\end{matrix}\right) \right\rangle,$$where $H_f$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$. Evaluating this gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: Please explain more.. In fact I think that I firstly find $D^{l}f((a,b);(h,k))=..$ this formula holds for $l=1$ and then, I apply the formula for $l-1$

Comment: I'm sorry, my first answer was incorrect. Let me know if you can understand this.

Comment: Were you able to come to the solution from this?

Comment: Such a hint is given in back of the book  @EricAuld

Comment: So were you able to understand it from the book's hint/my solution?