# Taylor's Theorem for Multivariate Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Please look at this theorem in Wiki regarding Taylor's theorem generalized to multivariate functions: [Multivariate version of Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Generalizations_of_Taylor.27s_theorem)

The version stated there is one that I'm not familiar with - most versions require that the $k+1$-th partials exist (and/or continuous) and the remainder term is different (due to the additional conditions).

For the 1-dimensional case, the $h_\alpha$ is easy to obtain. But for the multivariate case, how does $h_{\alpha}$ look like? The wiki article does not have any citations for that theorem so I'm wondering if anyone can point me to a source.

Comment: For comparison, can you cite a reference that uses the definition you are more familiar with?

Comment: @Orangutango Here: [Trench, Real Analysis](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF). You can find it on page 350.

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442330/a-problem-related-to-mean-value-theorem-and-taylors-formula/442373#442373

Comment: @AlexStrife the book you quoted has several missprints on the formula at page 350. I suppose what you mean is the Lagrange formula of the remainder as explained in wikipedia.

Comment: @Eric I've actually seen that already. The remainder term there involves partial derivatives of the $p$th order (in the wiki article notation, $k+1$-st order partials). What I need to know is that the remainder term can really be written in Peano form, as in the Wiki article.

Comment: Oh, I see. Note that if you divide the expression involving the $k+1$-st partials by $\|x-c\|^k$ you get something which still goes to zero as $x \to c$. Therefore the remainder is of the form $h_k(\Delta x)\cdot \|x-c\|^k$, where $h_k \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$. Another way of saying it is that the remainder $h_k(\Delta x) = o(\|\Delta x\|^k)$ at $\Delta x = 0$.

Comment: @Eric I'm sorry I didn't get that. I'm not sure if you're still referring to the post you linked or the wiki article. In any case, can you explain further?

Comment: @AlexStrife please take the time to make a precise statement in your question. It is difficult to understand what you really need if you make references to other sources with different notations.

Comment: I'm referring to the remainder I linked to...the multivariate version of the Lagrange form. Divide the remainder terms (they are homogeneous polynomials of degree $k+1$ in the $x_i - c_i$) by $\|x-c\|^k$.